# Javascript: Convert a plain array of nodes (with pointers to parent nodes) to a nested data structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, tree

I have read many of the solutions to this problem and for example am trying with array-to-tree

Given this data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 33,
    "parent": null,
    "name": "Wealth and Investment Management and Insurance",
    "code": "wm-0001",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": 34,
    "parent": null,
    "name": "Corporate and Investment Banking",
    "code": "cib-0001",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": 35,
    "parent": 33,
    "name": "WIMI Business Unit 1",
    "code": "WIMBU-0001",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

And using this code

```
var arrayToTree = require('array-to-tree');
var tree = arrayToTree(data, {
            parentProperty: 'parent',
            customID: '_id'
        });
```

I cannot understand why its orphaning my children? i.e. I am getting this back

```
[ { _id: 33,
    parent: null,
    name: 'Wealth and Investment Management and Insurance',
    code: 'wm-0001',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 34,
    parent: null,
    name: 'Corporate and Investment Banking',
    code: 'cib-0001',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: it looks like the parentProperty is the culprit - trying to find fix;

Comment: change the _id to strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `array-to-tree` doesn't know what to do if `_id` is of type `Number`;

Changing this converts the flat array to a tree structure.

You can loop through the array to convert the **keys** `_id`/`parent` to `string` if they are `number`;

I'll only edit this if you ask for it (but the above solves)

Comment: Thanks yes this work! Its a pain as I need an additional loop but it does work

Comment: glad it helped!